# Split lines without losing delimiter

Tags: python, split

What i want to do is split a line such as `>m27348020>m8918930` into a list in this format `['>m27348020', '>m8911830]`

Is there any way to do this using re.split?
The split would happen at the > symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of split you can easily do

```
import re
x=">m27348020>m8918930"
print re.findall(r">[^>]*",x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply split the string on the given separator and then simply concatenate the separator at the start of each split element.

```
separator = ">"

line = ">m27348020>m8918930"

print [separator+i for i in line.split(separator) if len(i)>0]

>>> ['>m27348020', '>m8918930']
```